# Make a full deb package with dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, installation, python

I'm working on a **offline** Debian Jessie server.
I want to install Python 3.4 on this server, so i tried to use the .deb package from the official repo.

My problem is that the DEB package does not include its dependencies so the installation with dpkg fails.

How can I get or make a full .deb package which includes Python's dependencies ?

**EDIT** : If it can be useful I have another Debian which is online.

Comment: did you have `build-essential` package installed on your debian server?

Comment: @GAD3R No, it's a minimal install...

Comment: @GAD3R Can I use build-essential on another Debian to make my .deb package ?

Comment: would grabbing the dependencies separately be good enough?

Comment: try the `apt-offline` the answer on [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)